# ¿Es posible utilizar un mismo objeto en más de una clase?

Tags: java, poo

Es posible utilizar un mismo objeto en más de una clase.

Ej; Crear un objeto en el método main:

```
public class Mats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flores rosa = new Flores();
        rosa.hola();
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Flores(){   
    public void hola(){
        system.out.print("Hola!");
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Otra(){
    //Aquí se podria utilizar el mismo objeto que yo cree en el metodo main
    //para llamar métodos en la clase Flores???

    //Sería algo como: rosa.hola();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow puede mirar esto si quieres -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour por otro lado acabo de editar su pregunta, puede ver que ahora esta diferente puede puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, puede acceder a editar presionado sobre el, le recomiendo que entre para que pueda ver como se formatea el codigo para que se muestre como esta ahora , basicamente es poner 4 spc, pero lo puede hacer seleccionando el codigo en el modo edicion y pulsando sobre { } que esta en la parte superior donde escribe el codigo, para futuras preguntas/respuesta Saludos

Answer (score 3):

Si entiendo bien su pregunta, y basandome en su codigo, sin hacer muchos cambios usted puede usar algo asi si con al decir el mismo `Objeto` se refiere a la misma instancia del `objeto` que un su caso se llama `rosa`:

```
public class Otra(){

//Aquí se podria utilizar el mismo objeto que yo cree en el metodo main para llamar métodos en la clase Flores???

//Sería algo como: rosa.hola();

    Flores floresMain;

    public Otra(Flores floresMain){     //<- simple Explicacion: le pedimos que nos pase un objeto del tipo Flores

          this.floresMain = floresMain; //<- simple Explicacion: Asignamos, usamos this entre otras porque los nombres coinciden asi los diferenciamos uno es el que se le pasa como parametro y el otro es el que esta en la clase. 

          floresMain.hola();
    }

    public void usoOTravez(){ //<-simple Explicacion: Creamos un metodo que hace uso del objeto

    floresMain.hola();
    system.out.print("Rosa is cool");

    }
}
```

.

```
public class Mats {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Flores rosa = new Flores();
rosa.hola();

Otra otraClase = new Otra(rosa); //<-simple Explicacion: Se crea un objeto del tipo Otra, y se le pasa el objeto rosa que es del tipo Flores, al constructor de la clase Otra

otraClase.usoOTravez(); //<-simple Explicacion: Usamos el metodo de la clase Otra.usoOTravez que este a su vez llama a al metodo de la clase Rosa.hola 
}
}
```

Pero lo interesante seria que es lo que quiere hacer pues, podria optar por otro enfoque llamadas estaticas, `herencia (link al final)`, u otra forma.(ahora estas usando el objeto Rosa rosa en la otra clase) teniendo lo anterior presente usted puede pasar la misma `instancia` del objeto a varias clase, de forma similar a la `Otra()` cambiando el nombre de la clase ect. pero basicamente es lo mismo si usted quisiera usar la misma `instancia` del objeto en mas clases.

---

> .

No tiene porque pasar la misma `instancia` del objeto en el constructor de la clase siempre, en este caso es asi porque se a definido la clase asi, solo tenga presente que se le podria pasar mediante un metodo que no sea el constructor de clase, pero creo que el codigo anterior lo ayudara a ver como funciona, le pongo un ejemplo mas aunque igual no es lo que busca o le parece mas complicado ahora pero es bueno que lo conozca.

```
public class Otra(){

//Aquí se podria utilizar el mismo objeto que yo cree en el metodo main para llamar métodos en la clase Flores???

//Sería algo como: rosa.hola();

    Flores floresMain;

    public Otra(){     

    }

    public void asignarObjeto(Flores floresMain){     //<- simple Explicacion: le pedimos que asigene el objeto del tipo Flores, usted puede leer sobre los get set en java

          this.floresMain = floresMain; //<- simple Explicacion: Asignamos, usamos this entre otras porque los nombres coinciden asi los diferenciamos uno es el que se le pasa como parametro y el otro es el que esta en la clase. 
    }

    public void usoOTravez(){ //<-simple Explicacion: Creamos un metodo que hace uso del objeto

    floresMain.hola();
    system.out.print("Rosa is cool");

    }
}
```

.

```
public class Mats {

public static void main(String[] args) {

Flores rosa = new Flores();
rosa.hola();

Otra otraClase = new Otra(); 

otraClase.asignarObjeto(rosa) //<-simple Explicacion: se le pasa el objeto rosa que es del tipo Flores, al metodo de la clase Otra el cual se encargara de hacer las asignaciones

otraClase.usoOTravez(); //<-simple Explicacion: Usamos el metodo de la clase Otra.usoOTravez que este a su vez llama a al metodo de la clase Rosa.hola 
}
}
```

Si tiene dudas o no sabe es un metodo get, puede buscar por Google o Youtube algo como `getter and setter java` para que entienda su funcionamiento, si decide usar la asignacion por el metodo y no por el constructor tenga cuidado de no usar el objeto sin que este este asignado, de toda formas no se preocupe demasiado por eso, el compilador seguramete se lo diga cuando esto ocurra.

(en este ejemplo se pasa un poco por alto la encapsulacion para hacerlo mas facil de entender pero se cuando lea sobre `Get` `Set`, podra ver que se a omitido los modificadores de acceso como pueden ser `private` ect.)

Aqui puede leer algo sobre los modificadores en java
http://programacion.jias.es/2012/07/modificadores-en-java/

---

> .

si se refiere al mismo objeto como tal usted simplemente puede hacer algo asi:

```
public class Otra(){

//Aquí se podria utilizar el mismo objeto que yo cree en el metodo main para llamar métodos en la clase Flores???

//Sería algo como: rosa.hola();

    Flores flores;

    public Otra(){     
     flores = new Flores();
    }

    public void usoOTravez(){ //<-simple Explicacion: Creamos un metodo que hace uso del objeto

    flores.hola();
    system.out.print("Rosa is cool");

    }
}
```

.

```
public class Mats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Otra otraClase = new Otra();//<- simple explicacion: este objeto contiene un objeto del tipo Flores pues se crea en la llamada al constructor

    otraClase.usoOTravez();//<- simple explicacion: Aqui se llama al metodo que este a su ves llama el metodo del objeto Flores
    }
    }
```

Notese que el mismo objeto no quiere decir la misma instancia pues puede que el objeto `Flores` tenga una variable `edad` que se le asigna a esta un valor digamos de 5 despues de ser creado o mediante un parametro al contructor de clase. Para una instancia digamos `Flores rosa`, pero si usted crea una instancia dentro de otra case esta instancia no tiene por que tener el mismo valor que se le asigno al la instancia de rosa, pues no es la misma instancia, aunque si el mismo objeto, espero entienda.

---

> .

Creo que podria mirar el link que le dejo debajo es sobre la herencia en java igual conociendo como funciona es lo que mejor se adapta a lo que quiere hacer, aunque para ello tendria que ajustar partes de su codigo, si no se adapata a lo que usted desea, pues por lo menos tendra conocimientos de como funciona para usarlo en otras ocaciones:

[Lista de videos sobre la herencia en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza)

---

> .

*se espera confirmacion de Luiggi de si esto es a lo que se referia con argumento en el metodo.*

**UPDATE:** Por recomendacion de [@Luiggi-mendoza](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/227/luiggi-mendoza) en el comentario, se toma como base para añadir otra forma mas que no habia mencionado pues es sincilla y puede que le ayude, pues me parece interesante para que la conozca, se añade lo siguiente:

```
public class Otra(){

    //Aquí se podria utilizar el mismo objeto que yo cree en el metodo main para llamar métodos en la clase Flores???

    //Sería algo como: rosa.hola();


        public Otra(){     

        }

        public void llamadaObjeto(Flores floresMain){     //<- simple Explicacion: se le pasa al metodo de la clase el objeto instaciado al cual se quiere usar/llamar

              floresMain.hola(); //<- simple Explicacion: Toma el objeto que se le paso a la funcion como parametro y hace una llamada a al metodo del objeto hola()   
        }
    }
```

.

```
    public class Mats {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Flores rosa = new Flores();
    rosa.hola();

    Flores rosa1 = new Flores();

    Otra otraClase = new Otra(); 

    otraClase.llamarObjeto(rosa); //<-simple Explicacion: Se le pasa como parametro el objeto instaciado, rosa.

    //de esta forma puedes usarlo para pasar deferentes instacias del objeto aqui le pasamos la instacia de rosa1
    otraClase.llamarObjeto(rosa1);

    }
    }
```

---

NOTAS: no he testeado el codigo asi que se lo puede tomar como un pseudo 
code.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, por teoría de POO, si es posible usar un mismo objeto en más de una clase, eso es herencia múltiple.

Comment: @SalahAdDin esto no se trata de herencia. Si tienes un objeto de una clase A (almacenado en una variable) entonces este objeto puede ser reutilizado en otro objeto de una clase B que no se relaciona con A por herencia. Para ello, lo que debes hacer es pasar el objeto de tipo A hacia el objeto de tipo B de alguna manera. En esta respuesta, se explican varias de ellas: como argumento en el constructor, como argumento via setter, seria interesante ver que tb puede ser como argumento en el metodo. Existen mas maneras pero esas son mas mas simples.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, esto es posible. Es más, este es uno de los propósitos de la programación, el reuso de los objetos. Te explicaré 3 formas simples (dos de ellas ya explicadas por @AngelAngel) y un par de formas un poco más sofisticadas. Para esto, utilizaremos tu case base y la única clase a modificar será `Otra`. Se asume, tal como indicas en tu ejemplo, que no existe una relación jerásquica entre `Flores` y `Otra`, es decir, ninguna es `super` clase de otra y tampoco comparten una clase padre. Se evitan validaciones como `if (variable == null)` y manejos de excepciones para simplificar los ejemplos.

### Pasar el objeto como argumento en el constructor

Cómo lograrlo:

- Necesitas declarar un campo (field) en `Otra` de tipo `Flores`.
- Debe haber un constructor público (`public`) o que sea visible para el cliente donde se reciba como argumento una variable de tipo `Flores`.
- En el constructor, se asigna el campo con el valor del argumento.

Ejemplo de implementación:

```
public class Otra {
    Flores rosa;
    public Otra(Flores rosa) {
        this.rosa = rosa;
    }
    public void hazAlgo() {
        rosa.hola();
    }
}

public class Mats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flores rosa = new Flores();
        Otra otra = new Otra(rosa);
        otra.hazAlgo();
    }
}
```

Detalles:

- La variable de tipo `Flores` se puede reutilizar en más de un método definido en `Otra`. Estos otros métodos no necesitan ser públicos.
- Se declara una **dependencia fuerte** de `Otra` hacia `Flores`. Esto es, para crear un objeto de tipo `Otra`, *necesitas* que exista una variable de tipo `Flores` para que `Otra` pueda funcionar.

Recomendaciones:

- Si vas a utilizar esta manera, apunta a que el campo de tipo `Flores` sea `final` y así no pueda ser sobreescrito. Esto facilitará el trabajo en concurrencia.

### Pasar el objeto como argumento vía setter

Cómo lograrlo:

- Necesitas declarar un campo (field) en `Otra` de tipo `Flores`.
- Debe haber un setter (método `set`) público (`public`) o que sea visible para el cliente donde se reciba como argumento una variable de tipo `Flores`.
- En el setter, se asigna el campo con el valor del argumento.

Ejemplo de implementación:

```
public class Otra {
    Flores rosa;
    public Otra() {
    }
    public void setRosa(Flores rosa) {
        this.rosa = rosa;
    }
    public void hazAlgo() {
        rosa.hola();
    }
}

public class Mats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flores rosa = new Flores();
        Otra otra = new Otra();
        otra.setRosa(rosa);
        otra.hazAlgo();
    }
}
```

Detalles:

- La variable de tipo `Flores` se puede reutilizar en más de un método definido en `Otra`. Estos otros métodos no necesitan ser públicos.
- Se declara una **dependencia débil** de `Otra` hacia `Flores`. Esto es, para crear un objeto de tipo `Otra`, *no necesitas* que exista una variable de tipo `Flores` para que `Otra` pueda funcionar. Puesto que no es obligatio, el código indica que existen funcionalidades de `Otra` donde no se necesita de `Flores`, y otras probablemente sí, así que se otorga libertad al cliente para utilizar el setter cuando sea necesario.

Recomendaciones:

- Resulta útil cuando el valor del campo `Flores` puede ser reemplazado o asignado a necesidad.
- No se necesita crear un nuevo objeto de tipo `Otra`. En cierto modo, se diría que ahorras memoria RAM, lo cual depende mucho para que clase de dispositivo estés programando: una aplicación backend de servidor esto es una cosquilla, para una aplicación móvil o un smart-watch puede ser el último fragmento de RAM que tiene a disposición.
- Al ofrecer esta libertad al cliente, la clase se torna frágil para su uso en ambientes concurrentes. No obstante, se puede utilizar pero existe la posibilidad que un cliente utilice el setter y afecte a otros hilos que utilicen la misma instancia de `Otra`.

### Pasar el objeto como argumento en el método

Cómo lograrlo:

- En el método necesario, debe declararse un argumento que sea una variable de tipo `Flores`.
- Utilizar la variable directamente en el método.

Ejemplo de implementación:

```
public class Otra {
    public void hazAlgo(Flores rosa) {
        rosa.hola();
    }
}

public class Mats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flores rosa = new Flores();
        Otra otra = new Otra();
        otra.hazAlgo(rosa);
    }
}
```

Detalles:

- La variable de tipo `Flores` se puede reutilizar en más de un método definido en `Otra` siempre y cuando estos métodos indiquen que existe un argumento de tipo `Flores` para ellos. Estos otros métodos no necesitan ser públicos.
- Se declara un **uso** de `Otra` hacia `Flores`. Esto es, la clase `Otra` ofrece múltiples funcionalidades y para alguna en particular se necesita de un objeto de tipo `Flores`.
- Puedes llamar al mismo método con una instancia diferente de `Flores`

Recomendaciones:

- Esta manera facilita el reuso de la funcionalidad en un ambiente concurrente.

Ahora, otras maneras más complejas, pero finalmente basadas en las tres de arriba. Estas se centran principalmente en código y explicación del mismo.

### Uso de una colección de objetos

Ejemplo de implementación:

```
public class Otra {
    public void hazAlgo(Map<String, Object> parametros) {
        Flores rosa = (Flores)parametros.get("rosa");
        rosa.hola();
    }
}

public class Mats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flores rosa = new Flores();
        Otra otra = new Otra();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("rosa", rosa);
        otra.hazAlgo(map);
    }
}
```

Detalles:
- Se envía un mapa de objetos hacia el método en `Otra`. Uno de los elementos contenido en el mapa es el objeto de tipo `Flores`. Se obtiene este objeto del mapa y se utiliza.

### Utilizar el patrón [Builder](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_%28patr%C3%B3n_de_dise%C3%B1o%29)

Ejemplo de implementación:

```
public class Otra {
    Flores rosa;
    public Otra() {
    }
    public void setRosa(Flores rosa) {
        this.rosa = rosa;
    }
    public void hazAlgo() {
        rosa.hola();
    }
}
public class OtraBuilder {
    private Flores rosa;
    public OtraBuilder setRosa(Flores rosa) {
        this.rosa = rosa;
    }
    public Otra construyeOtra() {
        Otra otra = new Otra();
        otra.setRosa(rosa);
        return otra;
    }
}

public class Mats {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Flores rosa = new Flores();
        Otra otra = new OtraBuilder().setRosa(rosa).construyeOtra();
        otra.hazAlgo();
    }
}
```

Detalles:

- No se crea una instancia de `Otra` directamente por el cliente, se utiliza un intermediario denominado `OtraBuilder`.
- Esto se utiliza para casos donde se requieren muchas variables y formas de crear una instancia de `Otra`. Para el caso actual, utilizar un builder es como utilizar una bazuka para eliminar un mosquito.

Comment: Gracias! Ya lo he podido solucionar.